# an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}([0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi])$

Tags: functional-analysis

define $(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^{2}$ the vectors $e_{n,m} \in L^{2}([0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi])$ with
\begin{align}
e_{n,m}=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{inx}e^{imy}
\end{align}

Prove that $(e_{n,m})_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^{2}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}([0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi])$.

I tried to prove this by calculation $\langle e_{n,m},e_{n,m}\rangle=1$ and $\langle e_{n,m},e_{i,k}\rangle =0$ for $n\neq i, m\neq j$ I got a really long expression and I probably made a mistake, but I think this can be to done an easier way. Has someone an idea?

EDIt: to prove this by calculation $\langle e_{n,m},e_{n,m}\rangle=1$ and $\langle e_{n,m},e_{j,k}\rangle =0$ for $n\neq j, m\neq j$ you see an answer in the answers.

Now I wonder, is this enough to talk about an orthonormal basis? No, it's only enough to talk about orthonormal. But Now I need to prove that those vectors are a basis, in other words that a function $f \in L^{2}([0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi])$ can be written as a lineair combination of the vectors. How do you start with this if  you don't know the function $f$?

Comment: in the inner product you need to complex conjugate the second entry. then it should be a straightforward calculation using fubini's theorem.

Comment: You could also try to proof that $\{ e_{n,m} | (n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ is dense in $L^2([0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi])$.

Comment: and why is it if you proof that?

Comment: An orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi])$ is not a basis of $L^2([0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi])$ as a vector space. So your remark that any $f$ needs to be written as a linear combination is incorrect. You have to show that the closure of the span of the set of $e_{nm}$ is $L^2([0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi])$ itself. Orthonormal basis $\not=$ vector space basis if the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use this
$$ \left<f,g\right>=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\bar{f}(x,y)g(x,y)dxdy. $$
Using
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(l-j)x}dx=2\pi \delta_{jl} $$
you have
$$ \left<e_{j,k},e_{l,m}\right>=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(l-j)x}e^{i(m-k)y}dxdy=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}. $$

Comment: I did use this, and I wrote verything with sin and cos but it's to much work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to write as sin and cos.

Comment: Then I don't see how I become 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Do the calculation.

Comment: Wait I think I understood something worng the whole time is $\bar{e^{ikx}}=e^{-ikx}$

Comment: Wait yes ofcourse, I'm so sorry I totally forget it's just adding a minus sing